# Why do Western countries not send more powerful weapons to Ukraine?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, nato

One of the most important reasons for Ukrainians being able to defend themselves against the Russian military is the weapons sent by various NATO / EU countries.

However, it seems that there is quite a reluctance on sending more powerful weapons compared to what would be possible and the [Russians are making progress in Eastern Ukraine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAR-hX8tbQU).

For example, the US is [sending advanced longer-range rocket systems to Ukraine](https://www.ft.com/content/ed20f1ec-f655-4f21-be79-f02646838824), but this happens quite late.

This delay in sending powerful weapons that would have helped the Ukrainian army push back the Russians faster has arguably led to more Ukrainian cities being almost completely destroyed.

I know that various countries might have various reasons, so I would exclude from this question the countries that still significantly depend on Russian oil and/or gas (e.g. Germany, Hungary).

What reasons have the other countries given for not sending more powerful weapons or what risks are attached with sending these weapons?

Comment: The underlying question is probably what all involved parties want to achieve there.

Comment: It takes time to get everything in order before they can send more powerful weapons?

Comment: I voted close this question as opinions-based, since i don't know how it could otherwise be answered. I mean, we can take their stated reasons: that they don't want to escalate, but they don't want russia to win, either... It's a [Balance of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_power_(international_relations)) strategy.

Comment: Interestingly,I saw this question just after I read this article:https://news.yahoo.com/macron-calls-not-humiliating-russia-115800597.html  What I understood was that Russia may do something large devastation out of desperation..

Comment: @RamanujanXXV: yeah, well, according to Macron Ukraine better surrender the Donbas now, because anything short of that would "humiliate" Putin. But that's seemingly [par for the French](https://www.politico.eu/article/where-is-france-anti-kremlin-russia-candidate-marine-le-pen-charles-de-gaulle-valerie-pecresse/).

Comment: They are extremely worried that a massive defeat and humiliation of Russia would result in a major escalation by the Russians (eg small yield nukes).  It's basically the model the US used with the mujahideen in Afghanistan. Get Russia tangled up in a war of attrition that decimates their military and economy.

Comment: The amount of conventional weaponry needed to save the situation in Ukraine is somewhat massive. The country had at least 14 divisions worth of equipment in 1992. That is now largely sold, lost and/or dated, but that was was _hundreds_ of tanks. Compare e.g. to the whole 222 Leclercs that France has at the moment. Look up the tonnage used by Russian artillery daily throughout the campaign. It would be easy to hurt Russia, anger Russia, but not to stop Russia with any practical amount of equipment that does not include actual trained troops.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev Actually it is very easy to stop Russia, because they have only been able to meaningfully advance and hold territory with the use of massed artillery barrages. Take out those guns and their momentum stalls, but Ukraine's air force is no longer able to do that - hence why Ukraine is asking for MLRS and other long-range weapons, which can. Ukraine does not need or want tanks because they would similarly be mauled by artillery, plus Ukraine has already taken out over 1,000 Russian MBTs, proving that the tank is a weapon of the past.

Comment: @IanKemp They are asking for MLRS because that's the only thing that survives for them in this war (I mean, that, its Soviet counterparts, and Tochka). They have already had Tochka. It's helping some, but not really a lot. If it would be "easy"... how many of those you would say are "enough"?

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev "Easy" in the sense of "easy to eliminate artillery", not "easy to eliminate **all** artillery".

Comment: The actual number of long-range systems sent is pretty low too. The US sent... ahem 4 M142 HIMARS launchers, the UK 3 sent 3 M270 MLRS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- It is in the interest of most Western countries to preserve/restore the territorial integrity of Ukraine. This is part of their interest to preserve the established international order, which benefits them.
- It is not in the interest of most Western countries to have the war escalate to other countries, *especially* not other EU or NATO countries.
- Russia has threatened to escalate the war if things don't go as Russia wants. It is *probably* not in Russia's interest to start another war while they are not winning the current one, but the West might be reluctant to bet too much that Russia sees the Russian interest the same way.

Net result, Ukraine is getting **considerably more aid and weapons** than other countries in similar positions, but **less aid and weapons** than Ukraine might wish.

Comment: Russia is in different position to many other aggressors in that they have a large arsenal of nuclear weapons, and quite possibly chemical and biological weapons as well.  They also have a leader acting irrationally.  While the likelihood of Russia using such weapons may be low, the hazard is so large that the overall risk can't be neglected (with respect to the third point - escalation)

Answer (score 14):

It's apparently because of the possibility [Ukraine will attack Russia with those weapons](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10868317/Biden-says-NOT-send-Ukraine-missiles-hit-Russia-Kremlin-warning.html). Russia has stated that they will consider that act a red line. It seems Western countries are concerned that Russia will be even more destructive if this red line is crossed (Russia is not using all its resources in the war right now; it is e.g. able to [conduct joint flights with China](https://www.businessinsider.com/russia-china-joint-bomber-flight-as-biden-quad-allies-meet-2022-5)).

Comment: I would take China out of this equation, as it has no political gain to be the pawn of Russia, but earn more hostilities from the West alliance.

Answer (score 14):

Just to highlight a few practical points:

- Modern weapon systems are expensive.  Few countries will have large surpluses that they can share without weakening their own defences at a time of heightened international tension.
- These systems are complex and likely to require specific training.  Can Ukraine spare front-line soldiers to spend weeks learning to use them effectively?
- Modern weapon systems are frequently networked as "systems of systems".  What appears to be a standalone weapon may be less effective without the sensors required for targeting.  Equipment may be incompatible with that currently in use.
- NATO and the former Warsaw Pact use different military standards.  Having incompatible munitions (for example) in the supply chain would complicate logistics.

Such practical problems complicate the task of providing useful support, even for willing allies.

Comment: Good point. I heard recently that lots of the Stingers we sent them are idle because Ukraine doesn't have the right batteries for them.

Comment: As an example of the munition-supply issue, the United States uses the M777 howitzer, which fires 155mm shells.  Ukraine (and Russia) uses the Msta-B howitzer, which fires 152mm shells -- similar enough that you can get the ammunition confused, but not similar enough to successfully fire the wrong ammunition.

Comment: Apparently Ukraine is running out of ammo for their Soviet type artillery, because most such ammo is made in Russia or China. Ukraine's own factories have been largely destroyed by Russian long-range strikes.

Comment: @Fizz if China is a shrewd merchant it would negotiate with the west to supply Ukraine with soviet ammo through western intermediate.

Answer (score 1):

Because there would come a point at which Putin would unleash his nuclear arsenal.

Right now the balance of power is unbelievably delicate and thus far, the free world can support Ukraine… but supporting is very different from fighting alongside.

Beyond that, could you clarify the exposition to your Question? As it stands, that seems largely to raise queries…

Comment: You are spot on. Everyone treads carefully because of the Russian nuclear weapons. I'm quite sure that without them, the war would already be lost for Russia. And for clarification, the question simply asks why Western countries are not helping more militarily. Quite good question if you ask me.